# Chart Not Showing All Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, charts

So i just started learning MVC, and Im learning to produce graph.
Im trying to pull data from SQL server and place it in X and Y axis.
My problem is, on the y axis, it populate till the end of my db but my x axis only shows 1 data from db.
Or am i doing everything wrong?
Do help. TQVM.

controller code:

```
public ActionResult MyBarGraph()
    {
        DB.Open();
        DataTable data = DB.GetTable("SELECT * FROM tblproduct");
        DB.Close();
        Chart c = new Chart(width: 800, height: 200);
        foreach(DataRow item in data.Rows)
        {
            c.AddSeries(
            chartType: "column",
            xValue: new[] {item["productname"]},
            yValues: new[] { item["quantity"] });
        }
        c.Write("png");

        return null;
    }
```

view code:

```
<div>
<h2>Bar Graph Example</h2>
    <img src="@Url.Action("MyBarGraph")" alt="SimpleChart" />
</div>
```

image :

[image: only Apple is shown]

updated-image:

[image: new problem]

Comment: What charting library do you use?

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan using System.Web.Helpers.Chart; ? am i answering it right? im not really familliar with this.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry about that. Tqvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this syntax instead:

```
            var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
            .AddTitle("Product Chart")
            .AddSeries(
            name: "Products",
            xValue: data.AsDataView(), xField: "productname",
            yValues: data.AsDataView(), yFields: "quantity")
            .Save("~/Images/Chart01.png", "png");
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** In order to customize your labels you need to pass a `Theme` file to your chart, like this:

```
            var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400, themePath: "MyTheme.xml")
            .AddTitle("Product Chart")
            .AddSeries(
            name: "Products",
            xValue: data.AsDataView(), xField: "productname",
            yValues: data.AsDataView(), yFields: "quantity")
            .Save("~/Images/Chart01.png", "png");
```

Add `MyTheme.xml` file to the root folder of your project, with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Chart>
  <ChartAreas>
    <ChartArea Name="Default">
      <AxisX IsLabelAutoFit="false">
        <LabelStyle Angle="-90" Interval="1"></LabelStyle>
      </AxisX>
    </ChartArea>
  </ChartAreas>
</Chart>
```

[image]

Comment: wow.. i thought that i need to loop the data. just shows how much more i need to learn. tqvm for your help. it works but just a few more tweaks if you could help. ive updated the question, added a new image after using your steps. the x axis is still not showing all the product name.. i really appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you mean not all your **data** is showing up or just the **labels**?

Comment: just the labels - productname, as you can see in the image, only roti and book is shown.

Comment: The chart may not be able to fit all labels depending on the number of columns and width of the labels. You may need, for instance, to rotate the label by 90 degrees (vertical positioning) so it can fit more labels.

Comment: ooo.. i just tried with 5 data. it shows. tqvm again. can you guide me on what should i search for to do what you just said, rotate the label.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Tqvm for your help again.

Answer (score 1):

You added a bunch of series with only one column for each series.

The correct approach to populate data should be like:

```
    c.Series.Add("srs");
    foreach(DataRow item in data.Rows)
    {
        C.Series["srs"].Points.Add(item["productname"], item["quantity"]);
    }
```

This way you will get one column for each data row.

Comment: i cannot use c.Series, as Chart  does not contain a definition for Series. it suggest me to change to c.AddSeries("srs") and in the loop, how do i call it back? tqvm

Comment: Try get rid of the foreach loop. You need to pass the the entire columns to XValue, and YValues[0]. No need to pass it row by row.

Comment: im sorry but i dont get it. how do i access each row in the database if i dont use foreach loop?

Comment: You can use a loop (or Lambda expression) to read the two columns into a IEnumerable, i.e. a List. Then pass the list to XValue and YValues (this has to be outside the loop).

Comment: is it possible for you to show it? i dont really know about Lambda expression or IEnumerable. really appreciate it.

Comment: Try xValue: data.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("productname")), yValues: data.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<Int32>("quantity"))

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in System.Web.Helpers.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The method or operation is not implemented.

Comment: sorry for annoying you with all this question.

Comment: new Chart(width: 800, height: 200)
                .AddSeries(
                chartType: "column",
                xValue: data.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("productname")),
                yValues: data.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<Int32>("quantity")))
                .Write("png");